# Strategy for multiple subscribers and flow of data using RxJava 2

Tags: java, android, performance, rx-java, rx-java2

I cannot decide how to implement this task correctly using `RxJava2`.

The problem is following. I am recording audio using `AuidoRecord`.

Currently I have implemented the custom `Flowable` class like that

```
private class StreamAudioRecordRunnable extends Flowable<short[]> implements Runnable {
    private int mShortBufferSize;
    private List<Subscriber<? super short[]>> mSubscribers = new ArrayList<>();
    private short[] mAudioShortBuffer;

    private void removeAllNullableSubscribers() {
        mSubscribers.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
    }

    private void notifyAllSubscribers(short[] audioBuffer) {
        removeAllNullableSubscribers();
        for (Subscriber<? super short[]> subscriber : mSubscribers) {
            subscriber.onNext(audioBuffer);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void subscribeActual(Subscriber<? super short[]> newSubscriber) {
        mSubscribers.add(newSubscriber);
    }

    private void notifyAllSubscribersAboutError(Throwable error) {
        for (Subscriber<? super short[]> subscriber : mSubscribers) {
            subscriber.onError(error);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            // Init stuff
            while (mIsRecording.get()) {
                int ret;
                ret = mAudioRecord.read(mAudioShortBuffer, 0, mShortBufferSize);                              
                notifyAllSubscribers(mAudioShortBuffer);
             }
        mAudioRecord.release();
    }
}
```

As you can see I am manually adding subscribers to the list. Then when I get new buffer all subscribers are notified.

I am guessing that this is not the most performant way to do this.

What I need

1. As far as this flowable running in a service. It should run until the service is alive, even if there are no subscribers.
2. Subscribers are not constant, they may subscribe and then unsubscribe, but the Flowable/Observable should still be running.
3. As the data emitted by the Flowable is the stream, subscribers should not be notified about already emitted items, they should only get current streaming data. Fire and forget.
4. The Flowable should run even all subscribers are gone.

Please suggest the right strategy to implement this.
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a Runnable?

Comment: @JohnWowUs, no this is just my minor mistake, I will get rid of it soon, as far as RxJava allows to specify the execution thread

Comment: @JohnWowUs what could you say about the implementation itself ?

Comment: Well I wouldn't use a subclass for one thing. I'd have a `ConnectableFlowable` as a member which subscribers could then obtain as a Flowable via a `hide`.

Comment: @JohnWowUs, according the documentation, `ConnectableFlowable` won't start emitting items until all subscribers are connected. This won't fit my requirements, I have an independent flow of audio data, that should be emitted independently from subscribers.

Comment: You can use `connect` to start your hot observable regardless of the number of subscribers. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
public class StreamAudioRecordRunnable  {
    private int mShortBufferSize;
    private short[] mAudioShortBuffer;
    private ConnectedFlowable<short[]> audioFlowable();

    public StreamAudioRecordRunnable() {
        audioFlowable = Flowable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<short[]>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(FlowableEmitter<short[]> emitter) throws Exception {
                try {
                    while (mIsRecording.get()) {
                        int ret;
                        ret = mAudioRecord.read(mAudioShortBuffer, 0, mShortBufferSize);                              
                        emitter.onNext(mAudioShortBuffer);
                    }
                    emitter.onComplete();
                    mAudioRecord.release();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    emitter.onError(e);
                    mAudioRecord.release();
                }
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).publish();  
    }


    public Flowable<short[]> getFlowable() {
            return audioFlowable.hide();
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        audioObservable.connect();      
    }
}
```

would be my preference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you explain the pros using this approach ?

Comment: Composition should be used rather than inheritance where possible . You don't have to manage your subscribers.